# MVC4 CheckboxFor HtmlAttributes issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, asp.net-mvc-4, html

I have a checkbox like this with defined value and text.

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.UserGroup.administration, new[] { new SelectListItem { Text = "True", Value = "1" }, new SelectListItem { Text = "False", Value = "0" } })
```

I would like to add another html attributes which is "id=1", but it gave me an error if I attempt to do so in new[] {...}
I get the following errors : “No best type found for implicitly-typed array”
Any idea?

Comment: Id will automatically be set based on the model being passed down I believe

Comment: Can you explain why you are using `SelectListItem` with a checkbox here?

Comment: @Gaz I wanted to manually set Id for each control

Comment: @Yannick Sorry that I am quite a beginner in MVC4, I was thought of we need to manually assign the attribute for checkboxes. Do let me know if I were wrong.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to manually set the control ID to `MyClass` you can do it like this:

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.UserGroup.administration, new { id = "MyClass" })
```

The other attributes should be mapped automatically if your `model.UserGroup.administration` is a boolean...